# Change web page content in real time without ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I realized at a moment with the help of firebug in stackoverflow.com, when someone accepted your answer,  suddenly your points got increased without any Ajax hit received to any method. Amazing, How is it possible?

Please advice so that i can try to implement this technique into my upcoming projects. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might be web sockets.

Comment: If it might be ajax, then is there any kind of approach to follow so that no can trace it in firebug.

Comment: It might  be using HTML 5 WebSockets and the WebWorker architecture.

Comment: Back when they implemented some of the new dynamic features it used to say "websockets started" or something like that in the console on newer browser. The console message has since been removed, but since some of the features on SO are still the same it's a safe bet to say it's using websockets, probably socket.io with node.js, but who knows ? Updating a number on a website when someone click on something should be pretty straigh forward even without ajax, and then just do a ajax call to a database to keep the numbers correct on refresh etc. No magic!

Comment: @ SidCool Web Workers are designed for multi-threading. You can run web socket in same thread.

Comment: Alex John: regarding your deleted question just now; please do _not_ delete questions once you have asked them. This risks rendering any pending answers as wasted effort, as mine was - if a question is poor, let the moderator close/delete it.

Comment: Ahh.. Thanks. But I did not have so much points to loose. You are right. I'll do the same as you suggested. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have looked into the net option. There are two ways I can tell.

1. Web Sockets
2. iFrame

Please have a look at http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/connectivity & http://html5demos.com/web-socket

But will work on limited browsers

Using iFrame with simple get request no ajax call will made but you will be able to see it  firebug net. This is what Facebook uses and all browser compatible.

Comment: Yes web sockets are part of HTML5 and only latest browser has this feature.

Answer (score 2):

It's using [WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebSockets/) instead of <del>AJAX</del> XMLHttpRequest in modern browsers. You can find more details about Stack Overflow's implementation on [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125677/new-feature-real-time-updates-to-questions-answers-and-inbox).

The main advantage of WebSockets is **the server can send an update to the browser the moment you receive an upvote**. Other methods, such as XHR and hidden iframes, require the browser to poll the server at regular intervals to get an updated vote count.

Comment: Is it possible to implement it with CakePHP or Codeigniter?

Answer (score 1):

you could use an image submit button and submit to an small iframe that displays the number.

otherwise you'd still be messing around with an hidden iframe and submits or gets posts in a hidden iframe.

If you really want a javascript less solution the form submits hidden/small iframe are the way to go.

Comment: 1vote up. But if more than 50% page content needs to be changed, and if I am going to use iframe, then google might not crawl my web page, as Iframe is not a good practice to use widely. Isn't it?

Comment: true, but google doesnt crawl ajax content either. You  could put links to the files with content into your xml sitemap for google and redirect to "container" page if a normal user views it.

Comment: Thanks Michael, Is there any kind of tutorial available so that I can learn about sitemap creation and rediecting while normal user views it.

Comment: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156184 for sitemap creation and http://www.gotfusion.com/tutsdl/frames_breakin.cfm for breaking into frames.